# asterisk confbridge - how to add japanese version

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I'am Using asterisk conference

When I join to conference it says

> Please Enter Pin Number

How can I Change it to Japanese Version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confbridge itself have params for channge all recording files.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/ConfBridge

You also can do

```
Set(CHANNEL(language)=jp)
```

before go confbridge.

Comment: Hello @arheops. Can i change the built-in audio?

Comment: You can chnage any file. There are no built-in.All files in /var/lib/asterisk/sounds/ folder